# Bar chart with rounded corners in Matplotlib?

Tags: matplotlib, bar-chart, data-visualization

How can I create a bar plot with rounded corners, like shown in this image? Can it be done with matplotlib?

[image: bar chart with rounded corners]

Comment: One can use a `FancyBboxPatch` as in [here](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/gallery/shapes_and_collections/artist_reference.html). It will be pretty cumbersome to construct the diagram from those, but sure possible.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

It looks like there's no way to directly add rounded corners to a bar chart. But matplotlib does provide a [`FancyBboxPatch`](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.patches.FancyBboxPatch.html#matplotlib.patches.FancyBboxPatch) class a demo of which is available [here](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/gallery/shapes_and_collections/fancybox_demo.html).

So in order to create a plot like shown in the question we could first make a simple horizontal bar chart:

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
# make up some example data
np.random.seed(0)
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.uniform(0,20, size=(4,4)))
df = df.div(df.sum(1), axis=0)
# plot a stacked horizontal bar chart
ax = df.plot.barh(stacked=True, width=0.98, legend=False)
ax.figure.set_size_inches(6,6)
```

This produces the following plot:

[image: a plot with regular rectangles]

In order to make the rectangles have rounded corners we could go through every rectangle patch in `ax.patches` and replace it with a `FancyBboxPatch`. This new fancy patch with rounded corners copies location and color from the old patch so that we don't have to worry about placement.

```
from matplotlib.patches import FancyBboxPatch
ax = df.plot.barh(stacked=True, width=1, legend=False)
ax.figure.set_size_inches(6,6)
new_patches = []
for patch in reversed(ax.patches):
    bb = patch.get_bbox()
    color=patch.get_facecolor()
    p_bbox = FancyBboxPatch((bb.xmin, bb.ymin),
                        abs(bb.width), abs(bb.height),
                        boxstyle="round,pad=-0.0040,rounding_size=0.015",
                        ec="none", fc=color,
                        mutation_aspect=4
                        )
    patch.remove()
    new_patches.append(p_bbox)
for patch in new_patches:
    ax.add_patch(patch)
```

This is what we get then:

[image: plot with rounded rectangles]

I gave the boxes a negative padding so that there are gaps between bars. The numbers are a bit of black magic. No idea what the unit is for `rounding_size` and `pad`. The `mutation_aspect` is shown in the last demo example, here I set it to 4 because `y` range is about 4 while `x` range is approximately 1.