# Seaborn or Matplotlib Boxplot with rounded corners

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, seaborn

I'd like to do a **boxplot** with rounded corners but not sure how. Saw a post to make rounded corners for barplot but no luck with boxplot. `ax.artists` is a list of matplotlib.patches.PathPatch objects and I think they control the box styles.

Below is some sample code

```
import pandas as pd 
import numpy as np 
import seaborn as sns 
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(100, 1), columns=['value'])
df['type'] = pd.Series(np.repeat(['type1','type2', 'type3', 'type4'], 25))
ax = sns.boxplot(data=df, x="type", y="value")
```

Comment: Do you mean violin plots? Or do you mean notches as on this site:(https://chartio.com/learn/charts/box-plot-complete-guide/#variable-box-width-and-notches) Otherwise, can you clarify what you mean with rounded corners.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are similar questions (e.g. [Bar chart with rounded corners](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58425392/bar-chart-with-rounded-corners-in-matplotlib) and [Seaborn barplot with rounded corners](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61568935/seaborn-barplot-with-rounded-corners)). These solutions need quite some adaptions to be usable here.

The boxplot's rectangles aren't stored as rectangles, but as patch artists.  To get their bounding box, the entent of their path needs to be calculated.

The parameters of [FancyBboxPatch](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.patches.FancyBboxPatch.html) need some experimenting. Setting `pad=0` makes the rounded rectangle occupy the same space. `mutation_aspect` (defaults to `1`) is needed to make the vertical boxes look well. For your own application, some fine-tuning might be needed.

```py
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.patches import FancyBboxPatch
from matplotlib.path import get_path_collection_extents
import seaborn as sns
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(100, 1), columns=['value'])
df['type'] = pd.Series(np.repeat(['type1', 'type2', 'type3', 'type4'], 25))
ax = sns.boxplot(data=df, x="type", y="value")

new_patches = []
for patch in reversed(ax.artists):
    bb = patch.get_path().get_extents()
    color = patch.get_facecolor()
    p_bbox = FancyBboxPatch((bb.xmin, bb.ymin),
                            abs(bb.width), abs(bb.height),
                            boxstyle="round,pad=0,rounding_size=0.2",
                            ec="black", fc=color,
                            mutation_aspect=0.2)
    patch.remove()
    new_patches.append(p_bbox)
for patch in new_patches:
    ax.add_patch(patch)
plt.show()
```

[image: seaborn boxplot with rounded corners]

Comment: I tried to adjust it from the same answer, but it was totally out of my hands. get_extents() is needed is what I learned. +1

Comment: Thank you so much for answering! This is exactly what I want. For tuning params, I don't quite understand what these parameters do but a couple for loops solved it.  This [demo](https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/shapes_and_collections/fancybox_demo.html#sphx-glr-gallery-shapes-and-collections-fancybox-demo-py) was helpful.