# How do put a white frame arround a plotly figure

Tags: python, plotly, bar-chart, plotly.graph-objects

My goal is to produce this plot:[image]

With this code:

```
import pandas as pd
import plotly.graph_objects as go

premium_growth_data = '{"Market":{"0":"Company"},"Class":{"0":"Total"},"total_2019_ytd":{"0":712725553},"total_2018_ytd":{"0":626756526},"total_2018":{"0":1211397008},"total_2017":{"0":1071172608},"total_2016":{"0":784732527},"yoy_2019":{"0":0.137164949},"yoy_2018":{"0":0.13090738},"yoy_2017":{"0":0.365016195},"rank_2018":{"0":7},"rank_2019":{"0":5},"share_2016":{"0":0.030046288},"share_2017":{"0":0.035641317},"share_2018":{"0":0.037034574},"share_2019":{"0":0.041049906},"gc_yoy_2019":{"0":0.050436263},"gc_yoy_2018":{"0":0.088362134},"gc_yoy_2017":{"0":0.150733851}}'
premium_growth_df = pd.read_json(premium_growth_data)
current_rank = premium_growth_df.rank_2018[0]
x2 = premium_and_rank_df["premium"]
y2 = premium_and_rank_df["rank"]
y2_text = ["You" if elm == current_rank else elm for elm in y2]
text = "$" + round(((x2.astype(float)) / 1000000)).astype("str") 
colors = ['steelblue',] * len(y2)
colors[y2_text.index("You")] = 'crimson'
trace3 = go.Bar(x=x2, y=y2, marker_color=colors, text=text, textposition="outside", width=0.2, orientation="h", showlegend=False)
fig = go.Figure([trace3])
fig.show()
```

I achieved this:

[image]

I`ve been googling quite extensively but I did not find a solution for

- "framing" the bar-plot with a white box
- making the corners of the bars "round"

Comment: [Bar chart with rounded corners in Matplotlib?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58425392/bar-chart-with-rounded-corners-in-matplotlib)I also looked for it, but unfortunately it doesn't have that feature, and I found an example implementation in matplotlib, so please refer to it. (It's not a horizontal bar graph.)

Comment: Thanks for referencing to that post - However, I would like to achieve that in plotly as it is interactive, which matplotlib is not.