# Polar bar chart with rounded corners in Matplotlib?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am trying to recreate this radial bar chart in matplotlib:
[image]

I can do it without problems using:

```
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
    import numpy as np
    import pandas as pd
    from matplotlib.patches import FancyBboxPatch
    
    color_dict = { "Sweden":"#5375D4", "Denmark":"#A54836", "Norway":"#2B314D" }
    
    colors = [ "#2B314D", "#A54836","#5375D4", ]
    
    data = {
        "year": [2004, 2022, 2004, 2022, 2004, 2022],
        "countries" : ["Sweden", "Sweden", "Denmark", "Denmark", "Norway", "Norway"],
        "sites": [13,15,4,10,5,8]
    }
    
    df= pd.DataFrame(data)
    
    df['sub_total'] = df.groupby('year')['sites'].transform('sum')
    df = df.sort_values(['countries', 'sites'], ascending=True ).reset_index(drop=True)
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(5,5), facecolor = "#FFFFFF", subplot_kw=dict(polar=True) )

x = len(df.year.unique())
countries = df.countries.unique()

for countries in countries:
    y = df[df["countries"] == countries].sort_values("countries", ascending = False)["sites"].values
    ax.barh(countries, np.radians(y*10))
  
  

ax.set_theta_zero_location('N')
ax.set_theta_direction(-1)
ax.set_rorigin(-1)
ax.set_thetamax(180)
```

Which produces: (i havent beautified it yet)
[image]

To create the round corners I was thinking of adding circles to both ends, but is there an easier way?

I have found this, but it doesnt work on polar charts:

[Bar chart with rounded corners in Matplotlib?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58425392/bar-chart-with-rounded-corners-in-matplotlib)
It generates this:
[image]
I want to do it in pure matplotlib (no plotly or seaborn,...)

Comment: I added it to the question :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of horizontal bars, you could plot thick lines with the rounded cap style like this:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

color_dict = {"Denmark": "#A54836", "Norway": "#2B314D", "Sweden": "#5375D4"}
countries = color_dict.keys()
values = [10, 8, 15]

fig, ax = plt.subplots(subplot_kw={"projection": "polar"}, facecolor="#FFFFFF")

for i, (c, v) in enumerate(zip(countries, values)):
    angle_range = np.linspace(0, v*10)
    r = np.full(len(angle_range), i + 1)  # identical radius values to draw an arc
    # plot a thick arc with the rounded cap style
    ax.plot([np.deg2rad(a) for a in angle_range],
            r,
            linewidth=20,
            solid_capstyle="round",
            color=color_dict[c])

# increase the r limit, making a bit more space to show thick arcs correctly
ax.set_rmax(len(countries) + 1)

# place custom ticks and labels
ax.set_rticks(range(1, len(countries) + 1))
ax.set_yticklabels(countries)

ax.set_theta_zero_location("N")
ax.set_theta_direction(-1)
ax.set_rorigin(-1)
ax.set_thetamax(180)

plt.show()
```

The result:
[image]